# How select the datepicker in selenium webdriver using ruby?

Tags: ruby, selenium, webdriver

I'm new to ruby automation and currently working on Selenium WebDriver using Ruby. I want to select the date from datepicker.

I'm able to identify the element but not able select the date. I tried using send_keys method but it doesn't work since the datepickers are read only and can select date only after clicking on it.

```
<input id="checkin" class="form-control hasDatepicker" type="text" autocomplete="off" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy" name="ch_in" vk_1adc8="subscribed">
```

I want to select the date 23rd from below table:

```
<div id="ui-datepicker-div" class="ui-datepicker ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all" > 
    <div class="ui-datepicker-header ui-widget-header ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all"> <table class="ui-datepicker-calendar"> 
         <thead>
             <tbody>
                <tr> 
                  <td class="available notranslate ui-datepicker-current-day" data-year="2016" data-month="2" data-event="click" data-handler="selectDay" data-original-title="" title=""> 
                     <a class="ui-state-default ui-state-active" href="#">23</a> 
                  </td>
               </tr>
            </tbody> 
        </table> 
     </div>
```

Comment: please share the html code

Comment: @fabersky .. updated the description with html code. Thanks !!

Comment: did you try with `driver.findElement(By.linkText("23")).click();`

Comment: @fabersky Yes, I tried with linktest but it didn't work. However I tried jquery and it works now . Thanks !!
`day = "23"`
`month = "2"`
`year = "2016"`
`test=@driver.execute_script("$(\"div#ui-datepicker-div  table.ui-datepicker-calendar  tbody  tr  td[data-year='" + year+ "'][data-month='" + month + "'] > a:contains('" + day + "')\").click();")`